# Saving data from GUI back to Google Spread Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to save data from active UI build in GUI back to spreadsheet. But cannot figure out how to retrive string value from text box in the UI. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
function saveChanges() {  
  var Text;
  var Location;
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  Text = app.getElementById('CompanyLegalNameTextBox').getText();
  Location = "C3";
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Location').setValue('Text');  
}
```

Getting error: TypeError: Cannot find function getText in object Generic.

Thank you si much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly explained in details in [the UI App documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp?hl=fr-FR), please read it before asking.

Answer (score 1):

The specific details you care for in the are the fact that `getElementById` returns a `GenericWidget` which doesn't support any get operations.

Another confusing aspect is Id and Name. Params into callback functions are passed in using name and `getElementById` uses Id (as the name implies). For simplicity, I usually set the Name and the Id of my widgets both at the same time to the same thing. Then you are able to pass a reference to your widget by adding it to the call back via the `addCallbackElement`

```
   ///snippet
   var textBox = app.createTextBox()
                   .setId('CompanyLegalNameTextBox')
                   .setName('CompanyLegalNameTextBox');

  app.add(textBox);
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('saveChanges');
  handler.addCallbackElement(textBox);
  button.addClickHandler(handler); //button defined elsewhere
```

And your call back code looks like this - notice the "e" parameter

```
  function saveChanges(e) {  
    var textValue = e.parameter.CompanyLegalNameTextBox;
    ///snippet 
  }
```